# How to delete a record using LinkButton and refresh the table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an HTML table to display a set of records from database after user entered a patient code or during Page Load when the patient code is passed through Querystring. Each data row has a Delete link button which is created dynamically.

I'd like to have the table refreshed after deletion. However, whenever the link button is clicked, it will postback and all the records will be wiped out unless I reload the data. If I reload the data again after deletion, there will be 2 times data fetching and the table rows will be doubled.

The first 2 rows of the tables are defined on the ASPX for easier styling purpose. If I cleared the table when fetching the data, the first rows will be wiped out as well. I have another 8 tables on different pages created in the same manner, hence I'd rather find other solution rather than defining and styling the rows from code behind.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The codes I use are as follow:

ASPX

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPatientCode" runat="server" Text="Patient Code : "></asp:Label>&nbsp; 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" name="Date" Text="Find" Width="90" CssClass="ButtonNormal" />
    <br /><br />

    <table id="tblDoctorInformation" class="PatientDetailsTable" runat="server">
        <tr><td colspan="2">DOCTOR INFORMATION</td></tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Doctor In Charge</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected PM As New PatientManagement.Common

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GetPatient()
    Else
        If txtPatientCode.Text <> "" Then
            GetPatient()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GetPatient()
    Dim sPatientCode As String = ""

    If IsPostBack Then
        sPatientCode = Trim(txtPatientCode.Text)
    Else
        sPatientCode = Trim(Page.Request.QueryString("PatientCode"))
    End If

    If sPatientCode <> "" Then
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = PM.ExecuteReader("SELECT LOGID,DOCTORNAME FROM PMV_DOCTORINCHARGE WHERE PATIENTCODE='" & sPatientCode & "'")

        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read
                Dim tRow As New HtmlTableRow
                Dim tCellDoctorName As New HtmlTableCell
                Dim tCellModifyLink As New HtmlTableCell
                Dim lb As New LinkButton

                'Doctor Name
                tCellDoctorName.InnerHtml = PM.GetString_TableCell(dr("DoctorName"))
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCellDoctorName)

                'Delete links
                lb.Text = "Delete"
                lb.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", False)
                lb.CommandArgument = dr("LogID").ToString()
                AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf DeleteRecord
                tCellModifyLink.Controls.Add(lb)
                tCellModifyLink.Align = "Center"
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCellModifyLink)

                tblDoctorInformation.Rows.Add(tRow)
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
    GetPatient()
End Sub

Protected Sub DeleteRecord(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim lbNew As New LinkButton
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    lbNew = sender

    bResult = PM.DeleteMultiRecord(lbNew.CommandArgument, lbNew.CommandName, Session.Item("UserID"), sResult)
    If Not bResult Then
        MsgBox(sResult, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Deletion was not successful")
    Else
        GetPatient()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a GridView and a DataSource?

Comment: Hi, the actual table actually consist of more columns and the data on some columns are either configured as a hyperlink or are styled based on certain condition. I don't have much knowledge whether GridView has such flexibility. I only use GridView for displaying data without any modification.

Comment: I think the GridView has such flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched around and it seems dynamic handler is best to be declared during `PageInit`. For my case, as the link button control needs to carry some values on the respective data row, it seems I can't avoid calling `GetPatient` to create controls.

To move on with the issue, I did a workaround by using Javascript. I created a `hidLogID` hidden field on ASPX page. I changed the link button to an `<a>` control and call a javascript function passing the `dr("LogID")`. The javascript function will assign the value to `hidLogID` and submit the page. `PageLoad` will call `DeleteRecord()`when `hidLogID` value is not blank. The value for `hidLogID` will be cleared on `DeleteRecord()`.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Before Deleting a record, try to place a `PatientID` in Textbox and Delete the record, then Table will Display the records matching with the TextBox input.

The Problem is with `PageLoad()` method, if the TextBox is Empty And It is a Postback, then `GetPatient()` method will not be called. So try to modify the `PageLoad()` Method.

Better to remove IsPostBack condition in `PageLoad()`.

Comment: I tried to avoid calling `GetPatient()` method after postback by `lb` but it will never go to `DeleteRecord`, unless I call `GetPatient()`. Do you have any idea how to handle this situation?